# Connecting a Tom Tom GPS to a computer

Tags: gps

I have a Tom Tom ONE Classic.

When I connect it to the computer I get a message "Do you want to connect it to the computer", I answer yes, then nothing appears to happen.

While it is connected I cannot use the GPS.

When I disconnect I get the message "writing route information".

Is this expected functionality. I had hoped for some UI on the computer to be able to see what routes had been updated etc and be able to use the GPS while it is charging.

Comment: Do you have the [TomTom HOME](www.tomtom.com/home) software installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, when you connect a Tom Tom to a computer, that is when you can do maintenance operations to it, such as updating maps, changing voices, transfering files, etc. Because of that, it can't be used as a GPS. If you want to use it while it's charging, you should be using the power adaper that plugs into the 12v outlet (cigarette lighter)